# Is it possible to have default properties of nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my application there are already many nodes with different labels. We are passing property value at the time of creation. I wanted to have 2 properties for all the nodes by default (like creationDate and createdBy). Is there any possibility from configuration side that we can pass these property by default to all the nodes at the time of creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by configuration, you only mean `neo4j.conf`, then no. You need some code to actually compute the value of the properties anyway: how do you represent the date, how do you determine who created the node?

To do that, you could deploy an extension in Neo4j to intercept the creation of nodes through [transaction events](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/#transactions-events) by implementing a [`TransactionEventHandler`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html): you'll get the [`TransactionData`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionData.html) which directly exposes the nodes that were created, on which you can then set the audit properties you want.

The handler is registered through [`GraphDatabaseService`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html), which can be obtained at startup by implementing [`PluginLifecycle`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/server/plugins/PluginLifecycle.html) and exposing the implementation via the Service Locator mechanism (put the class name in `META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle`).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I implemented the TransactionEventHandler. I am able to solve my problem with this.